# How do I loop through this hidden field format

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do i Loop through the hidden field items and put in Session using  PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4035591/how-do-i-loop-through-the-hidden-field-items-and-put-in-session-using-php)

I have a hidden Field  which contains this format  which contains the Set of rows separated by ';'(semicolon)
and each row contains some columns  name separated by ':'   (colon) and  each column value  separated by ',' (comma)
so  my format would be ENO:123,ENAME:XYZ,SAL:1200; ENO:598,ENAME:AIR,SAL:1300;  which is what stored in hidden field

So How do i grab each column  such as ENO ,ENAME  and SAL  their values  for any number of rows  written to hidden field 
so i have my own custom  session function  where i can set the key and value .So on looping the values 
I should be able to put  MyCustomSessionFunction('ENAME',??????).How do i fill this .

I did not get Proper Replies Earlier .can  anyone please help me

```
   $hiddenformat  =  $_POST['hiddenfield'];



   string(80) "ENO:1000,ENAME:B,SAL:10;ENO:1000,ENAME:S,SAL:100;"
```

when i vardump($hiddenformat) I am getting the above format  .How do i explode and loop and assign each value to my 
   custom  session function

```
     foreach( $outer_array as $outer_key => $inner_array ) 
   {
     foreach( $inner_array as $key => $value ) 
     {

     }
   }
```

Comment: Please watch the formatting (and spelling). Use the preview window. Press CTRL-K to format code properly.

Comment: Isn't this basically the same thing you asked here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4035591/how-do-i-loop-through-the-hidden-field-items-and-put-in-session-using-php

Comment: and here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037213/how-do-i-iterate-through-this-loop-get-each-item-separately. Asking the same question over and over and is not acceptable.

Comment: @MarcB: I did not get the Replies None of them are working .I tried all

Comment: Then put a bounty on it. Don't have enough points for that? Then wait to build up your reputation. Don't litter the site with your dups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, it was.
It's just to say that around that, you have to explode() by ";" and in the loop use Marc's code, since there are multiple Sets of data in the string

Answer (score 3):

```
$hiddenformat = $_POST['hiddenfield'];
$parts = explode(',', $hiddenformat);

foreach($parts as $part) {
    $bits = explode(':', $part);
    ...
}
```

Given a $hiddenformat of `ENO:1000,ENAME:B,SAL:...`, the first explode will split the line at every comma, giving you a $parts array  that looks like:

```
$parts = array(
    0 => 'ENO:1000',
    1 => 'ENAME:B',
    2 => 'SAL:.....
);
```

Yuu use foreach to loop over this $parts array, and split the $part at every colon (:). So at each stage, $bits will look like:

```
$bits = array(
    0 => 'ENO',
    1 => '1000'
)
```

and then on the next iteration will

```
$bits = array(
    0 => 'ENAME',
    1 => 'B'
)
```

and so on. What you do with those individual chunks is up to you.

And yes, this was all present in the answers of the other questions. You just had to do a bit of work to put it all together.